# Plaid - Error with Sandbox `set_verification_status` request when simulating expired verification

Tags: plaid

While trying to test the `VERIFICATION_EXPIRED` error state in sandbox for an item which is `pending_automatic_verification`, I attempted to make a request to https://plaid.com/docs/api/sandbox/#sandboxitemset_verification_status. I have used this endpoint before to simulate a successful verification when including `"verification_status": "automatically_verified"` in the request body.

According to the documentation, it is also possible to send the status `"verification_status": "verification_expired"`, but when I made that request, the webhook which ultimately gets sent is the "success" event, with the code
`AUTOMATICALLY_VERIFIED`. I am including the webhook request body (minus account/item ids) which I logged below:

```
{   
  "account_id": "[the account id]",
  "item_id": "[the item id]",
  "webhook_code": "AUTOMATICALLY_VERIFIED",
  "webhook_type": "AUTH"
}
```

The request body I sent to the endpoint was (via the postman collection):

```
{
  "client_id": "{{client_id}}",
  "secret": "{{secret_key}}",
  "access_token": "{{access_token}}",
  "account_id": "{{account_id}}",
  "verification_status": "verification_expired"
}
```

Is there something else needed in the request body to coerce the "VERIFICATION_EXPIRED" webhook?

Comment: yeah i'm looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up! This is a bug on Plaid's side, and the owning team has been informed and is investigating. I don't think there's anything you can do at this point to coerce the webhook.

Comment: Great, thank you! I have just been sending the request I expect Plaid to send to my app's webhook handler, but looking forward to a time when I can just use the sandbox endpoint.